# User Cannot Select SQLite db Location from UWP App

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, uwp

Using code to [Preserve access to a StorageFolder](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-task-snippets/blob/master/tasks/Folder-access-preservation.md) stolen from [Karl Erickson](https://github.com/KarlErickson)

```
public static async Task<StorageFolder> GetOrPickAndRememberFolderAsync(string key)
{
    if (StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.ContainsItem(key))
    {
        return await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(key);
    }
    var picker = new FolderPicker();
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    StorageFolder folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    if (folder != null)
    {
        StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace(key, folder);
    }
    return folder;
}
```

our UWP app is able to browse to and remember the location of a SQLite database chosen by a user. This should give read/write permissions on that folder.

The dbContext is instantiated like this

```
    public dbContext(string dbPath)
    {
        databasePath = dbPath;
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=" + databasePath);
    }
```

This code works if the user chooses the default local storage location for the app.

```
        var picker = new FolderPicker();
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        StorageFolder folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

        StorageFolder dbFolder = await GetOrPickAndRememberFolderAsync("LocalDbFolder");
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(dbFolder.Path, "MySQLite.db");

        using (var db = new dbContext(dbPath))
        {
            db.Database.Migrate();
        }
```

However if the user chooses any other location (such as their Documents folder) the app fails with the error `"SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'."`

Why would that be, given the user has given the app explicit permissions on the selected location through the picker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.
SQLite requires native file access. To use the native file access, you should put the sqlite .db file to the application local folders - Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder or tempfolder.

If you use the file/folder picker, you can get the storagefolder item. But, if the folder is outside of your application, ALL of file accesses are done with OS's broker process. SQLite can't access the such of folders.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @pnp0a03. I expected it was impossible but we can never be sure until someone tells us why.

Comment: This isn't a real solution since that isn't always an option.  The SQLite team needs to get with MS and fix this (inexplicably still a problem in 2019).